# What's the best among these expressions if in a formal news report?

Tags: expressions, collocations

1. the railway will become operative on Saturday.
2. the railway will begin operation on Saturday.
3. the railway will come into use on Saturday
4. the railway will be put into use on Saturday.
5. the railway will make its first journey this Saturday.

It's the first sentence of a Chinese-to-English translation. The Chinese version of it is "周六，世界上最高的铁路——青藏铁路将开始运行。"  And the first half of the translation goes as follows:

1. **The Qinghai Tibet Railway, the highest in the world, begins operation on Saturday.** The first train will leave Golmud, the second largest city of Qinghai Province in Northwest China, for Lhasa, in the Tibet Autonomous Region, in the morning.
2. The train leaves Golmud at about 2,800 meters above sea level, winds through the towering Tanggula Mountain Pass at 5, 072 metres, and finally arrives in Lhasa at 3, 650 metres .
3. A ceremony will be held at the Golmud Railway Station at about 9: 30 am to see off the train, according to sources with the Ministry of Railways.
4. At least 1,000 journalists from home and abroad have come to Qinghai and Tibet to cover the event along the rail line. People can witness the ceremony and the whole day's trip live on television, radio and …

Comment: There are any number of ways of expressing what you're trying to say (including, for example, *The railway **starts operating** on Saturday*, or just ***...opens** on Saturday*). But there is no "best" expression for the context. Note that only ***trains*** (or other things / people that actually *move*) can "make journeys", not railways.

Comment: I quite like the word "commence" if you're being formal. "The railway will commence operations on Saturday."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly these are all ok, though No.s 4 and 5 could both be improved:

`the railway will be put to use on Saturday, by [something relevant].`  (`to` not: `into`)

`Trains will make their first journey this Saturday [on the new railway].` (Railways don't move.)

In both cases the portion in square brackets are merely hints.